# Validate all ASPX, ASCX and HTML files when building

Tags: asp.net, html, visual-studio, validation

Visual Studio will show errors in an AS?X or HTML file in the Error List window when you have that file open. However once you close the file the error(s) are removed from the Error List.

Is it possible to validate all AS?X and HTML files in one action (ideally as part of building) and show all errors at once?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using a web application project you can add a build task that uses the **aspnet_compiler** to compile the application.